# Serve multiple formats with bigvideo.js

Tags: javascript, joomla, video.js

I set up a website background using bigvideo.js on a joomla website. The video is working great. The only thing I could not figure out yet is how to embed multiple file formats. I put all javascript in a external file. I would like to serve ogv and webm as well.

Here is how my javascipt looks like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var BV = new jQuery.BigVideo();
BV.init();
if (Modernizr.touch) {
BV.show('/videos/bg03.jpg');
} else {
BV.show('/videos/bg03.mp4',{ambient:true, preload:true});
}
});
```

Best regards
Jay

Comment: do you mean you would like use video 2 if the format for video 1 is not supported by the browser?

Comment: Or are you hoping for something like the HTML5 video tag? Adding multiple sources for better support. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: Hi Lodder, thanks for your replay. I want to serve multiple formats for better browser compatibility. So scenario #1.

Answer (score 0):

From the [bigvideo.js website](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/):

```
$(function() {
  var BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false});
  BV.init();
  BV.show('vids/river.mp4', {altSource:'vids/river.ogv'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Got it! I still struggle with IE and Opera. The both most lovely browsers ever existed :) They dont take the alternative video somehow..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use more than one alternate source:

```
var BV = new $.BigVideo();
BV.init();
if (Modernizr.video) {
    if (Modernizr.video.h264) {
        BV.show('/assets/river.mp4', {ambient:true, doLoop:true});
    } else if (Modernizr.video.ogg) {
        BV.show('/assets/river.ogv', {ambient:true, doLoop:true});
    } else if (Modernizr.video.webm) {
        BV.show('/assets/river.webm', {ambient:true, doLoop:true});
    } else {
        // browser probably don't support the above video formats, do something...
    }
} else {
    // Video is not supported, do something...
}
```